# count of matching rows and select 30 from each count group in hive

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

How do I count the matching rows for the below sample data

```
ID    Attribute 1  Attribute 2 
        1   A   AA 
        2   B   CC 
        3   C   BB 
        4   A   AA 
        5   C   BB 
        6   D   AA 
        7   B   AA 
        8   C   DD 
        9   A   AB 
        10  A   AA
```

the out put should look like this

```
 ID    Attribute 1  Attribute 2     count(Attribute1+Attribute2)
        1   A   AA  3
        2   B   CC  1
        3   C   BB  2
        4   A   AA  3
        5   C   BB  2
        6   D   AA  1
        7   B   AA  1
        8   C   DD  1
        9   A   AB  1
        10  A   AA  3
```

and then select 50% of rows from each count group. ex : for the mtaching row (A,AA) I need to select only 2 occurances. which would give me the the ID (1 and 4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the query:

```
select * from (select product_category_id,
count(1) over (partition by product_category_id) cnt,
row_number() over (partition by product_category_id) rn
from products) p where rn <= 0.5 * cnt;
```

Here is the sample result, product_category_id, cnt and then row number. In your case you need to have your two attributes in partition by clause.

```
59  24  1
59  24  2
59  24  3
59  24  4
59  24  5
59  24  6
59  24  7
59  24  8
59  24  9
59  24  10
59  24  11
59  24  12
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do with SQL query like this.

```
SELECT *, 
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM table AS t2
        WHERE t1.[Attribute1] = t2.[Attibute1] 
          AND t1.[Attribute2] = t2.[Attibute2]) AS 'count(Attribute1+Attribute2)' 
FROM table AS t1
```

Comment: This is invalid Hive syntax.  You can't have a subquery in a select statement.